# Unable to parse JSON file to CSV with jq-string ("") and array cannot be added

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

Here is output.json: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJo5SnYOHAcjng-jww

i have issues in sts:AsumeRole.Principal.Service part when have multiple Services

```
Principal": {
                        "Service": [
                            "ssm.amazonaws.com", 
                            "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                    }
```

in my code below, it's `.Principal.Service` field.
If have only one service, no issues

```
 "InstanceProfileList": [
            {
                "InstanceProfileId": "AIPAJMMLWIVZ2IXTOC3RO", 
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
                            "Statement": [
                                {
                                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                                    "Effect": "Allow", 
                                    "Principal": {
                                        "AWS": "*"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "RoleId": "AROAJPHJ4EDQG3G5ZQZT2", 
                        "CreateDate": "2017-04-04T23:46:47Z", 
                        "RoleName": "dev-instance-role", 
                        "Path": "/", 
                        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:role/dev-instance-role"
                    }
                ], 
                "CreateDate": "2017-04-04T23:46:47Z", 
                "InstanceProfileName": "bastionServerInstanceProfile", 
                "Path": "/", 
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:instance-profile/bastionServerInstanceProfile"
            }
        ], 
        "RoleName": "dev-instance-role", 
        "Path": "/", 
        "AttachedManagedPolicies": [
            {
                "PolicyName": "dev-instance-role-policy", 
                "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:policy/dev-instance-role-policy"
            }
        ], 
        "RolePolicyList": [], 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:role/dev-instance-role"
    }, 
    {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                    "Effect": "Allow", 
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": [
                            "ssm.amazonaws.com", 
                            "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

If only one service exists, no issues, but if more than one then getting error `string ("") and array (["ssm.amazonaws.com) cannot be added`

How to get all values for Principal.Service in one row.

My code:

```
jq -rc '.RoleDetailList 
  | map(select((.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement | length > 0) and 
        (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service) or 
        (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS) or 
        (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Federated) or 
        (.AttachedManagedPolicies | length >0) or 
        (.RolePolicyList | length > 0)) )[] 
      | [.RoleName,
         ([.RolePolicyList[].PolicyName,
          ([.AttachedManagedPolicies[].PolicyName] | join("--"))] 
         | join(" ")),
       (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[] 
        | .Principal.Federated + "" + .Principal.Service + ""+.Principal.AWS)] 
       | @csv' ./output.json
```

Desired output:

```
"dev-instance-role","dev-instance-role-policy","ssm.amazonaws.com--ec2.amazonaws.com--*"
```

Current output:

```
"dev-instance-role","dev-instance-role-policy","*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding additional condition to check whether `.Principal.Service` is type of either `array` or `string`:

```
jq -rc '.RoleDetailList 
        | map(select((.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement | length > 0) and 
        (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service) or 
        (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS) or 
        (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Federated) or 
        (.AttachedManagedPolicies | length >0) or 
        (.RolePolicyList | length > 0)) )[] 
        | [.RoleName,
           ([.RolePolicyList[].PolicyName,
           ([.AttachedManagedPolicies[].PolicyName] | join("--"))] 
        | join(" ")),
         (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[] 
        | .Principal.Federated + "" 
          + (.Principal.Service | if type == "array" then join("--") else . end) 
          + "" + .Principal.AWS)] 
       | @csv' ./output.json
```

The output:

```
"ADFS-Administrators","Administrator-Access ","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"ADFS-amtest-ro","pol-amtest-ro","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"adfs-host-role","pol-amtest-ro","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role","AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier--AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker--AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role","AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth--AWSElasticBeanstalkService","elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
"AWSAccCorpAdmin","AdministratorAccess","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpAdmin","AdministratorAccess","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpPowerUser","PowerUserAccess","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling","AutoScalingServiceRolePolicy","autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
"AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalk","AWSElasticBeanstalkServiceRolePolicy","elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
"AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing","AWSElasticLoadBalancingServiceRolePolicy","elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
"AWSServiceRoleForOrganizations","AWSOrganizationsServiceTrustPolicy","organizations.amazonaws.com"
"AWSServiceRoleForRDS","AmazonRDSServiceRolePolicy","rds.amazonaws.com"
"Cloudyn","ReadOnlyAccess","arn:aws:iam::432263259397:root"
"DatadogAWSIntegrationRole","DatadogAWSIntegrationPolicy","arn:aws:iam::464622532012:root"
"datadog_alert_metrics_role","AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-66abe1f2-cee8-4a90-a026-061b24db1b02","lambda.amazonaws.com"
"dev-instance-role","dev-instance-role-policy","*"
"ec2ssmRole","AmazonEC2RoleforSSM","ssm.amazonaws.com--ec2.amazonaws.com"
"ecsInstanceRole","AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"ecsServiceRole","AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole","ecs.amazonaws.com"
"flowlogsRole","oneClick_flowlogsRole_1495032428381 ","vpc-flow-logs.amazonaws.com"
"companyDevShutdownEC2Instaces","oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1516271285849 ","lambda.amazonaws.com"
"companySAMLUser","AdministratorAccess","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyAzureAD"
"irole-matlabscheduler","pol-marketdata-rw","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"jira_role","","*"
"lambda-ec2-ami-role","lambda-ec2-ami-policy","lambda.amazonaws.com"
"lambda_api_gateway_twilio_processor","AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-f47a6b57-b716-4740-b2c6-a02fa6480153--AWSLambdaSNSPublishPolicyExecutionRole-d31a9f16-80e7-47c9-868a-f162396cccf6","lambda.amazonaws.com"
"lambda_stop_rundeck_instance","oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1519651160794 ","lambda.amazonaws.com"
"OneLoginAdmin","AdministratorAccess","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/OneLoginAdmin"
"OneLoginDev","PowerUserAccess","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/OneLoginDev"
"rds-host-role","","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"rds-monitoring-role","AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole","monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com"
"role-amtest-ro","pol-amtest-ro","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"role-amtest-rw","pol-amtest-rw","ec2.amazonaws.com"
"Stackdriver","ReadOnlyAccess","arn:aws:iam::314658760392:root"
"vmimport","vmimport ","vmie.amazonaws.com"
"workspaces_DefaultRole","SkyLightServiceAccess ","workspaces.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Thanks Roman,it seems it works for all except dev-instance-role

Comment: Please ignore last comment, i think all is fine, thanks a milion !!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that .Principal.Service is either a string or an array of strings, so you need to handle both cases. Consider therefore:

```
def to_s: if type == "string" then . else join("--") end;
```

You might want to make this more generic to make it more robust or for other reasons.

You might also want to streamline your jq filter to make it more intelligible and maintainable, e.g. by using jq variables.  Note also that

```
.x.a + .x.b + x.c
```

can be written as:

```
.x | (.a + .b + .c)
```

Comment: thanks @peak, but how to modify my code ? to include your suggestions